# How to write an asterisk (*) symbol in superscript of a Greek letter in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

With reference to following figure, I want to write Δ* instead of Δ in the `Xlab`. I am using following line in my `R` code.

```
g=ggplot(SS4, aes(x = Delta, y = SRE, group = Estimators, colour = Estimators)) + geom_line(size=1.1)+xlab(expression(Delta))+ theme(legend.position="none",axis.text=element_text(size=12))
direct.label(g, list(first.points, hjust = 1.1,vjust = 1)).
```

[image]

How should I modify `xlab(expression(Delta))`, so that I am able to write Δ*? I have tried `xlab(expression(Delta^{*}))`, but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use paste() within expression()

```
xlab(expression(paste(Delta, "*")))
```